# Accessing array of floats inside an array of class objects in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class

I have some probably simple to solve issue with accessing array of floats inside an array of class objects.
Inside my Excel document I declare a class TData with some properties like

```
Public weight As Double
Public segments As Variant
```

Then inside a module I declare an array of objects and a function to modify the data:

```
Dim dataset(126) As Object

Function modify()

   Set dataset(0) = New TData
   dataset(0).weight = 50
   dataset(0).segments = Array(5.5,2,1)

   Debug.Print dataset(0).segments(0) ' this produces an error 451
   t = dataset(0).segments
   Debug.Print t(0) ' this is fine and prints the correct answer

End Function
```

If I try to access the value directly with line "dataset(0).segments(0)" I'll get an error 451 "Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object". If I assign the array to a variable first, I can access the value.

Now I don't understand why I can't access the value of the nested array. I guess it's some specific syntax which I didn't find anywhere. The thing is, when I add "dataset(0).segments" to the watches, it lists the values with exactly the above notation of "dataset(0).segments(0..2)".

Comment: `Debug.Print dataset(0).segments()(0)`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Now it looks like this returns a ByValue value, as trying to do `dataset(0).segments()(0) = 7.2` is valid but doesn't modify the original array. I'm currently considering to just use a Let method, but is there also a notation to directly write into the array?

Comment: I think you'll need to pull the array out if you want to modify it, or create a setter method on the object.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Tim:

I've deleted my previous Answer and replaced it with what Tim provided and was accepted by auther.  The error was a syntax error even I failed to catch.  I'm changing my answer for the community, but 100% credit goes to Tim.  If Tim posts the answer he should get the accepted answer check mark.

Debug.Print dataset(0).segments()(0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the concept of OOP isn't violated. I explicitly create a new instance of the class TData with the `new TData`statement at the first position of the Object array, which has explicitly 126 reserved fields. It's properties are at this point uninitialized or default, but getting initialized in the two following lines, the array implicitly with the `Array(0,0,0)` notation. From that point, all required properties are valid within the object at dataset(0).

Comment: I don't think I did a good job explaining myself.  I didn't mean to imply that OOP was violated.  In your question you asked why can't you access the floating numbers in the array directly.  My answer was aimed at that question.  It was my opinion that you already had working OOP code and you were just wondering why you had to access the array inside an object by creating yet another variable.  If this is not what you were asking about, can you please clarify what you are trying to find out?

Comment: Ah, okay. If I access an array inside an array of objects in, for example python I would just write `print(dataset[0].segments[0])` to get, or `dataset[0].segments[0] = 5.4` to set the value inside the array property of the object array. In VBA the line `t = dataset(0).segments(0) `produced an error, and as Tim pointed out, I had to write `Debug.Print dataset(0).segments()(0)`to have read access. So his comment was the correct answer to the initial question. I, however can't set the value with this notation. Which I added as a 'bonus' question :)